# Private function as friend of other class

Tags: c++, class, encapsulation, friend

I've got a following code written in C++:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Window;
class Level
{
    int level;
    int get(Window& w);
public:
    Level(void): level(3) {}
    void show(Window& w);
};

void Level::show(Window& w)
{
    cout << get(w) << endl;
}

class Item
{
    static const int item = 8;
};

class Window
{
    friend int Level::get(Window& w);
    int window;
public:
    Window(void): window(2) {}
    void show(void);
};

void Window::show(void)
{
    cout << "window" << endl;
}

int Level::get(Window& w)
{
    return w.window + level;
}

int main()
{
    Window wnd;
    Level lvl;
    wnd.show();
    lvl.show(wnd);
    cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

I want to have access to private member of class `Window` only accessible by friend function `get`, which is also private function of class `Level`. When I'm trying to compile I've got an error C2248. Is that possible to make private function as friend of other class?

Comment: some indentation might help

Comment: Try making `Level` friends with `Windows` i.e. add the `friend class Window` to `class Level`.

Comment: @Gucu112 nice :-) Now, `friend class Window;` within `Level` or conversely `friend class Level;` within `Window` would do the job. What would be the problem in this?

Comment: I know I can do that using friend between classes, but I'm looking for a way to access only what I want from `Window` that can be done only by class `Level`.

Comment: @Gucu112 I am not sure if this can be done or if it pays off the needed complexities in design. But for sure you may e.g. have `Level` derive a `Base` class that contains `get` and is a friend of `Window`.

Comment: @Gucu112 Btw, now `Level::get` has access to the entire class `Window`, not "only what you want".

Comment: @iavr Yes you're right, but I've got access to other class only in this function and that's what I'm looking for ;)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why can't a PRIVATE member function be a friend function of another class?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26956176/why-cant-a-private-member-function-be-a-friend-function-of-another-class)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Must friend declaration names be accessible?](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_closed.html#209) quotes the standard wording that "[a] name nominated by a friend declaration shall be accessible in the scope of the class containing the friend declaration", and gives a rationale for the existence of that (somewhat odd-looking) rule.

Comment: TL;DR: _in such cases, an easy workaround is simply to befriend the entire class rather than the specific member function_ - issue closed 20 years ago LOL :D Thank you @Stephan for linking it :)

Answer (score 4):

If I read the standard right, this looks like a compiler bug (unusual I know).

11.3/5:

> When a friend declaration refers to an overloaded name or operator,
>   only the function specified by the parameter types becomes a friend. A
>   member function of a class X can be a friend of a class Y.

Note that it doesn't say "*public* member function", just "member function". To me this implies that the privacy of the friendship-receiving function shouldn't be relevant to the granting of friendship.

Comment: "Reading" the standard is beyond me unfortunately, but I confirm that the code in the question fails in both GCC and Clang.